# Mail php - errors with form

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm wondering ...

In the head of the doc is the mail body and it is the details in the body of the document.
They don't match because I made some html changes but I can't just past it into it I have to almost go through it manually, does this make sence? Lol

Like it does this for the php code '.round($mon_pay_shield_wmant).''

and where ever there is ' in the html it puts this \

What am I doing incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That was painful to read, but I think you want to use `stripslashes`, if you're having problems where a `'` is being converted to a `\'`. You should also read up on `magic_quotes`, and decide if you want it on or off.